# pathnames with spaces in batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a problem with spaces in directory names in a batch script.

I store a base directory and then use that to make subdirectories and files, something like:

```
set basepath=c:\some\path
set logdir=%basepath%\log
set logfile=%logdir%\test.log
```

But the basepath on some servers have spaces in it.  Earlier I used `dir /x` to get the shortened 8.3 names but I encountered one server where this doesn't work (apparently there is some setting to disable this, and I don't have privileges to turn it back on).  So now I'm trying to figure this out.  I need to concatenate filename/directories to basepath, which may have spaces in it.  I tried using double quotes, but it didn't work.

At the command prompt, you can do things like `cd "some path"\with\spaces` using a combination of double quoted directories and non-double-quoted directories.  But this doesn't work in a batch script.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What error are you getting when doing this? You should be able to have spaces in the basepath path and then concatenate the rest on.

Comment: I was using double quotes incorrectly, like `set basepath="c:\some\path"` and concatenating to that.  The error I was getting was "filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect".  As MC ND and Rob K answered below, I should just double quote the final command, which works great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put double quotes around the environment variable only when you need to actually use it.

```
set basepath=c:\some\path with spaces
set logdir=%basepath%\log

xcopy *.log "%logdir%"
```

Then reference it as `"%logdir%"` and it will expand to `"c:\some\path with spaces\log"`. This works because `set` puts *everything* after the `=` <strike>except for</strike> *including* trailing white-space into the environment variable.

Comment: Not really. If there are spaces at the end of the `set` command assigned value, they are included in the value of the variable.

Comment: You are correct. I was thinking it trimmed it. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
set "basePath=c:\somewhere\over the rainbow"
set "logDir=%basePath%\logs"
set "logFile=%logDir%\kansas.log"

>> "%logFile%" echo This is a test
cd "%logDir%"
```

Don't insert quotes inside the variable values (unless it is necessary).

Use quotes surounding the `set` command to ensure no aditional spaces are stored in variables and to protect *special* characters.

Place quotes in the correct places in the final commands that make use of the variables.