# How to open destination with spaces in batch

Tags: batch-file, space

I need help on how do you open a file or copy a file to a destination that has spaces in it.

```
copy C:\Users\\OneDrive\Desktop\MyFile\download.jpg C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

pause
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use spaces in the Command Prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376113/how-do-i-use-spaces-in-the-command-prompt)

Comment: [How to write a full path in a batch file having a folder name with space?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7347501/995714), [pathnames with spaces in batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23253725/995714)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `""` to your source and destinations.

```
copy "C:\Users\\OneDrive\Desktop\MyFile\download.jpg" "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
```